# Gradle: run a clean up task at every execution (test, build, etc.)

Tags: gradle

I have a simple custom task that cleans up some local properties files to work for the given dev environment. I'd like Gradle to run this task every time I run *any* command, e.g., test, build, clean, etc.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: To the person who downvoted: could you kindly explain why? I don't see how the question is inappropriate or invaluable or trivial. Thanks

Comment: The need for this is a smell. (I didn't downvote the question.)

Comment: I know it is. Terrible code smell. However this is part of migrating a 3 yrs old legacy app to use Gradle as its build tool and there are a lot of very rough edges to it. I'm doing the best I can in cleaning up and moving things around. However some big changes will happen very slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way is to declare the dependency on every task such as:

```
task myclean() << {
    println "myclean"
}
task mytask1(dependsOn: myclean) << {
    println "mytask1"
}
task mytask2(dependsOn: myclean) << {
    println "mytask2"
}
```

Alternatively you can add a dependency to every task after they have been declared:

```
task myclean() << {
    println "myclean"
}
task mytask1() << {
    println "mytask1"
}
task mytask2() << {
    println "mytask2"
}
projects.tasks.findAll { it != myclean }.each { it.dependsOn << myclean }
```

Comment: A somewhat more idiomatic version is `tasks.matching { it != myclean }.all { it.dependsOn myclean }`. In particular, this will also match tasks added further down in the build script or in a different build script.